# Bonjour service discovery not finding hosts

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, bonjour

I am trying to implement the Bonjour NetServiceBrowser in Swift3 in order to discover hosts on my network.

When I manually search in the terminal using the following command I will find the hosts.

```
dns-sd -B
```

However, when I try to use the NetServiceBrowser in Swift (see code below), it will only print "starting search..". I implemented this class by following the [Bonjour documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/BrowsingForServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001077-SW4).

I do not understand what is going wrong. Does Bonjour work different for Swift? I could not find a working example online. I have tried several variants on the `domain` ("local", "local.", "") or several variants for `name`.

```
class ZeroConf: NSObject, NetServiceBrowserDelegate, NetServiceDelegate{

    var browser: NetServiceBrowser!
    var services = [NetService]()
    let domain = "local"
    let name = "_http._tcp"



    func startSearch(){
        self.services.removeAll()
        self.browser = NetServiceBrowser()
        self.browser.delegate = self
        self.browser.searchForServices(ofType: name, inDomain: domain)
    }


    func netService(_ sender: NetService, didNotPublish errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        debugPrint(errorDict)
    }

    func netServiceBrowserWillSearch(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser) {
        print("starting search..")
    }

    func netServiceBrowserDidStopSearch(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser) {
        print("Stoped search")
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didNotSearch errorDict: [String : NSNumber]) {
        print("error in search")
        debugPrint(errorDict)
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
        print("found service")
        services.append(service)
        debugPrint(service)
    }

    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didRemove service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
        if let ix = self.services.index(of:service) {
            self.services.remove(at:ix)
            print("removing a service")
        }
    }

    func netServiceDidResolveAddress(_ sender: NetService) {
        print("did resolve address")
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks lame but is services array allocated?

Comment: The code is supposed to work. However if you run it in a playground you need to enable `needsIndefiniteExecution` of `PlaygroundSupport` due to the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: @ystack yes it is allocated at the same line as it's declaration

Comment: @vadian no, it is not in playground

Comment: I just copied the code into a playground and it works as expected.

Comment: Hey guys help Me. My code stop at netServiceBrowserWillSearch and I dnt know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't working for me. I tried to execute the code from the main loop while it apparently should be called from a different thread. Hence, I changed my code in `startSearch` to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.browser.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        self.browser.searchForServices(ofType: self.name, inDomain: self.domain)
        RunLoop.current.run()
}
```

Comment: Hey guys help Me. My code stop at netServiceBrowserWillSearch and I dnt know what to do...